# Disk Management in Windows 2012 R2, where is it?

Tags: diskmanagement, windows-server-2012-r2

In Windows Server 2012 R2 I am unable to find the option to reassign the drive letter for a CD/DVD drive where the disks are normally managed. So I can reassign for hard drives, but not for optical drives? What gives?

Since `compmgmt.msc` runs the Server Manager, I am wondering which method I am supposed to use.

So how can I reassign the drive letter for optical drives without going through hoops on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: Your "question" contains two completely different questions, and the second one "How can I reassign the drive letter for optical drives?" is not answered by the accepted answer. Suggest you split this second one into a new question, or remove it, to improve the quality of your "question".

Comment: @JohnC: Actually my ""question"" is over two years old and most people seem to have understood what I was after the Disk Management MMC snap-in, as also suggested by the ""question"" title ... and yes, I realize there are probably other ways. But that's what I wanted, what the people answering understood and what I got and accepted :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Run `diskmgmt.msc` just like previous versions of Windows.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed what I want. How do I get there from the GUI as in previous versions? `Win+R` and then starting `diskmgmt.msc` worked fine, though.

Comment: From the GUI, right-click the "Start button," and choose Computer Management. Then click Disk Management in the new window.

Comment: @RyanRies: I think we have a different version of Windows Server here. When I open "Computer Management", the "Server Manager" opens. And the exact reason why I wrote the question was that I was stumped by the absence of "Disk Management" in that new window that opened. I remember the times this worked on Windows Server, but it didn't in 2012 R2 and I just checked 2012 behaves the same in that regard.

Comment: @RyanRies: never mind. It's possible to start the good old "Computer Management" from the "Server Manager" as well and there indeed I get to see disk management. Which makes me wonder how to start the "Computer Management" without getting served the "Server Management". I know, I'm complicated like that :)

Answer (score 5):

It is really easy to get to by default.  You will probably even be a bit annoyed you didn't notice it.

Simply right-click on the Windows logo button.  Then start the Computer Management.  Most of the other common tools you use for managing your system are also linked there.

[image: right click windows.]

Comment: I didn't notice it because with ClassicShell it's not there. I am used to get there by right-clicking "My Computer" and then choosing "Manage". Unfortunately exactly that method does *not* work as expected.

Comment: Pfft, ClassicShell.

Comment: @0xC0000022L There are so many ways to get to this, you would have had to _actively avoid them_. Just going to the Start screen would be sufficient; the old standby Administrative Tools is right there. And if you don't like that, click the down arrow to go to Apps and Computer Management is right in front of you.

Comment: This work on Server 2016 as well.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, compmgmt.msc is not the Server Manager.   The link in the shell was changed on 'This PC' to point to server manager, clicking "Manage" no longer calls 'compmgmt.msc', but it is still available.

Create a shortcut to 'compmgmt.msc' or 'diskmgmt.msc' and you can pin those to start or taskbar.  I am not aware of any registry setting to convert the 'This PC' Manage link back to compgmt.msc as of yet, but if I find one I will ping back.

I am talking about 2012-R2 in case it matters.

Comment: I found a registry method to re-enable the compmgmt.msc from Manage, if anyone cares to ask, I will post it then.

Comment: Link to method - reposted as trebek style question.   http://serverfault.com/questions/561522/can-we-restore-my-computer-manage-to-prior-functionality-in-server-2012-r2

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can simply run:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
```

To get the same information in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the start button, and choose Disk Management from the pop-up menu.
Alternatively, you could click on "Tools" in Server Manager, and then click "Computer Management" from the drop-down menu.  Disk Management will be in the tree within the left pane.